# How do I change a list item class on drop using an id with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, class, html-lists

I have 7 defined images in my css that I want to be able to pull into my stage and change list items by an id. There are 7 buttons in a left column that on drop I want to display different images of different sizes and animation in the right column. Right now I have all my classes defined, but can only currently the one class dropped. I'm trying to write an if statement that will handle this, but am having no luck. Is there a better way of doing this? I feel I'm pretty close.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="hide-overflow">
        <ul id="all-colls-list" class="droptrue ui-sortable">
                <li id="music" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-music.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="nav" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-nav.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="climate" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-seats.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="phone" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-phone.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="weather" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-weather.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="email" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-email.svg" /></a></li>
                <li id="calendar" class="sortedli"><a href="##"><img src="img/icon-calendar.svg" /></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="sortable" class="stage ui-state-highlight">
           <div id="frame">
             <ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue ui-sortable"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var lists = [{
"listid": "#all-colls-list",
"connectid": "#coll-selected-list"
}, {
"listid": "#coll-selected-list",
"connectid": "#all-colls-list"
}];
$.each(lists, function(i, list) {
$(list.listid).sortable({
connectWith: list.connectid,
opacity: 0.7,
start: function(event, ui) {
if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
$(ui.item).addClass('dropped');
} 
else {
$(ui.item).addClass('sorted');
}
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
$(ui.item).switchClass('dropped', 'sortedli');

} else {
$(ui.item).switchClass('sortedli', 'droppedli');

}
}
});
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropped {
height: 337px;
background-image: url('img/map.png') !important;
}

.droppedclimate{
 height: 104px;
background-image: url('img/climate.png') !important;
}

.droppedweather{
height: 143px;
background-image: url('img/weather.png') !important;
}

.droppedcall{
height: 110px;
background-image: url('img/ongoing-call.png') !important;
}

.droppedmusic{
height: 168px;
background-image: url('img/no-clue-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedlicalendar{
height: 158px;
background-image: url('img/calendar-sm.png') !important;
}

.droppedemail{
height: 121px;
background-image: url('img/email-sm.png') !important;
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're trying to do here. Maybe you could set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's my JSFiddle - [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/lukeslytalker/xyg92r6c/3/).

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do - [Twitpic](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BwEd8MuIAAAwb08.png).

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle for what I'm working on. http://jsfiddle.net/1cnjrcgg/2/